# Is there a better way to assign two variable to two others conditionally?

Tags: c#, optimization

I wrote this code, but it feels like it could be a bit more elegant:

### Relevant code only:

```
GameObject newBall;
GameObject pathBall;
if (tag.Equals(pathBallTagName))
{
    newBall = other.gameObject;
    pathBall = gameObject;
}
else
{
    newBall = gameObject;
    pathBall = other.gameObject;
}
```

### Entire .cs file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using BallDelegate;

public class BallCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    public Spline mySpline;
    private SplineController mySplineController;

    public AllBallManager abm;

    public string pathBallTagName = "PathBalls";
    public string ballTagEnd = "Balls";

    public BoxCollider front;
    public BoxCollider back;
    public BoxCollider spawnArea;

    public string frontName = "BallBox Front";
    public string backName = "BallBox Back";

    public bool isInSpawn = true;

    void Start() {
        mySplineController = GetComponent<SplineController> ();
        BoxCollider[] frontBack = GetComponentsInChildren<BoxCollider> ();
        foreach (BoxCollider bc in frontBack)
            if (bc != null) {
                if (bc.name.Equals (frontName))
                    front = bc;
                else if (bc != null && bc.name.Equals (backName))
                    back = bc;
            }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (mySplineController)
        {
            mySplineController.go = true;
            if (mySpline)
                mySplineController.gravSpline = mySplineController.currentSpline = mySpline;
        }
        if (other == spawnArea) {
            isInSpawn = true;
        }
        else if (!isInSpawn) {
            BallDelegateCS bd = other.gameObject.GetComponent<BallDelegateCS>();
            if (bd) // only balls, no other game objects
            {
                GameObject newBall;
                GameObject pathBall;
                if (tag.Equals(pathBallTagName))
                {
                    newBall = other.gameObject;
                    pathBall = gameObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    newBall = gameObject;
                    pathBall = other.gameObject;
                }
                while (newBall.transform.parent)
                    newBall = newBall.transform.parent.gameObject; // make sure we don't get BallBall
                abm.MakeWayFor(newBall, pathBall);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        if (other == spawnArea) {
            isInSpawn = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete and it misses some important elements. To me it looks clean. The only improvement that I can suggest is to use an enum instead of a magic string in if condition and if you are planning to use a string you can specify if this comparison is case insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

One alternative, note how we *must* store the bool result to ensure identical semantics (otherwise you risk calling tag.Equals twice... which in addition to performance considerations might change its result between calls or have side effects!)

```
bool swap = tag.Equals(pathBallTagName);
GameObject newBall = swap ? other.gameObject : gameObject;
GameObject pathBall = swap ? gameObject : other.gameObject;
```

Alternatively one could implement a Swap function elsewhere:

```
GameObject newBall = other.gameObject;
GameObject pathBall = gameObject;
if (tag.Equals(pathBallTagName)) Swap (ref newBall, ref pathBall);
```